# PresentModalViewController, PushViewController, then DismissViewController with a new view shown?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigation controller setup. I was hoping to do this:

From one of the views, I presentModelViewController:animated:, the user selects one of three options, after selecting I want the UINavigationController behind the modal view to change (the user will not see this), then I want to dismissModalViewControllerAnimated to reveal the new view.

Is this possible using the built-in modal view? Or will I need to create a view, add/animate it to the rootViewController so its not in the same stack as the UINavigationController?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modal view is a view you show modally on top of another view to interrupt the user from the current task. If I understand you correctly, you need two modal views and the selection user make on first modal view will decide what will show as the second modal view. Is that right?

If that's the case, you can make your main view to be the delegate of your first modal view, and send data back to the main view when the user makes a selection, and then main view dismiss the modal view (it's the main view's responsibility to dismiss it). And then based on user's input, you create another view and pop it modally. To make it animate correctly, you need to set the animation of the dismissing of the first modal view to be NO, and then make the animation of populating second modal view to be YES.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The idea was more the selection on the modal view will decide what the UINavigationController navigates to

Comment: That's the same idea, in the delegate method you will do in your main view controller, once you received the data from your modal view, dismiss it, then push another view then you navigate to it.